# How to change android launcher activity at runtime?

Tags: android, android-activity, passwords, android-manifest

I am working on an android app which has a default launcher activity whenever the user launches the app.

But the user will have the option to enable password in settings and if the user enables password I want show password activity as the launcher activity instead.

How can I achieve this at runtime?

Comment: I didn't see that thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can't.

consider writing some code in the activity defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to forward the user onto another activity if required.

Comment: I have already implemented that.But I thought it might have any alternate solutions.thank you for the response.